# Not all typescript files compile to js using atom-typescript

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, angular

I'm following a tutorial to build routing in Angular2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=10&v=ZsGRiHSaOxM It shows partial pages built with .ts and in each case a companion .js file.  My Atom editor with atom-typescript compiles my app.ts file to app.js as I change it, but my partial pages in another directory do not compile, as best I can tell.

When the file is homePage.ts, the console error is - cannot find homePage.js  When the file is homePage.js, the console error is - unexpected token @ on line (where @Component is).  I have   "compileOnSave ": true in my tsconfig, and that file is in the top level project directory.

I tried putting fileGlob in tsconfig, from the documentation, as follows

```
"filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
],
```

Nothing changed.

My compilerOptions are:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "charset": " UTF-8",
    "declaration": false,
    "diagnostics": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "version": true
},
```

Do I need both .ts and .js files for all components, and if so, how do I make that happen with atom-typescript?  Or why do I get the unexpected token @ error?

Comment: The error about `@` is a traceur issue. Did you add it in your project? In your video the guy does it. And yes, you need both files : you write in typescript and the compiler converts it into regular javascript (which is what the browser really uses).

Comment: check this, this is a minimal project to get up and running with Angular 2 and Typescript, maintained by an Angular team member -> https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play.ts

Comment: Eric, thanks.  Yes I have traceur in the index.html page with other script loads, as follows - <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>

Comment: jhadesdev, thanks.  That would probably work - Kozlowski knows his stuff.  My objective is to learn details about building Angular2 and use Atom with atom-typescript because I have a hunch all of these are a bright wave of the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or why do I get the unexpected token @ error

You need to have `experimentalDecorators` set to `true`. So :

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "charset": " UTF-8",
    "declaration": false,
    "diagnostics": true,
    "experimentalDecorators", true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "version": true
},
```

FWIW this is how decorators are implemented in the TypeScript compiler

Comment: I changed tsconfig to the above, plus   "compileOnSave ": true  (Also, it should be "experimentalDecorators": true, )  After many attempts Atom compiled and made the .js file for 1 of the routes. I made the second partial page .ts file and I have not yet been able to get Atom to compile it.  I repeatedly get a Console error of - not found partialPage2.js  and when I make changes in Atom, I do not get the yellow or green box that describes compile status.  It emits, it says I have no errors, but only occasionally compiles.  Any thoughts?  I may have code errors, and will review for that soon.

Comment: Adding "experimentalDecorators": true,  fixed the unexpected token @ error,  and for some reason, atom-typescript is compiling every time now without errors.  Thanks.  Now to fix my router errors.